# Trying to get node-webkit console output formatted on terminal

Tags: webkit, node-webkit

Fairly new to node-webkit, so I'm still figuring out how everything works...

I have some logging in my app:

```
console.log("Name: %s", this.name);
```

It outputs to the browser console as expected:

```
Name: Foo
```

But in the invoking terminal, instead I get some fairly ugly output:

```
[7781:1115/085317:INFO:CONSOLE(43)] ""Name: %s" "Foo"", source: /file/path/to/test.js (43)
```

The numerical output within the brackets might be useful, but I don't know how to interpret it.  The source info is fine.  But I'd really like the printed string to be printf-style formatted, rather than shown as individual arguments.

So, is there a way to get stdout to be formatted either differently, or to call a custom output function of some sort so I can output the information I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually gave up, and wrapped console.log() with:

```
log = function() {
   console.log(util.format.apply(this, arguments));
}
```

The actual terminal console output is done via `RenderFrameHostImpl::OnAddMessageToConsole` in chromium, with the prefix info being generated via `LogMessage::Init()` in the format:

```
[pid:MMDD/HHMMSS:severity:filename(line)]
```

The javascript console.log is implemented in console.cc, via the Log() function. The printf style formatting is being done at a higher level, so that by the time the Log() function (or similar) are called, they are only passed a single string.

It's not a satisfying answer, but a tolerable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to create a command line interface to go along side my UI and had a similar problem. Along with not logging the values as I wanted I also wanted to get rid of the [pid:MMDD/HHMMSS:severity:filename(line)] output prefix so I added the following:

```
console.log = function (d) {
  process.stdout.write(d + '\n');
};
```

so that console logging was set back to stdout without extra details. Unfortunately also a work around.